# Android - Where and how to save a profile picture

Tags: android

I'd like that when the user is registering into my app he could take a photo or choose from gallery his picture to be used in the app.
I'd like to save this picture in internal app folder, this way I don't need to ask for storage permission (I think!).
I wasn't able to to that.
For now, I have the Uri of the image.
How can I do this?

Comment: You still might need permission if you plan to read this image later.  I would guess that an app which wants to access your images would need permission.

Comment: I'm sure that if you google "android store image in internal app folder" you will find all the info you need

Comment: `save this picture in internal app folder`. What do you consider to be the `internal app folder` ?

Comment: To store the image you should require storage permission then you can create sub folder with any name you want and can store your image there

Comment: `To store the image you should require storage permission`. Not needed for internal storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `Bitmap` from `URI` and save into local storage. To get `Bitmap` from :

```
public static Bitmap getBitMap(Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{


InputStream input = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

  BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  onlyBoundsOptions.inDither=true;//optional
  onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
  input.close();

  if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1)) {
    return null;
  }

  int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

  double ratio = (originalSize > THUMBNAIL_SIZE) ? (originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE) : 1.0;

  BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
  bitmapOptions.inDither = true; //optional
  bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//
  input = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
  input.close();
  return bitmap;
}

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio){
  int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int)Math.floor(ratio));
  if(k==0) return 1;
  else return k;
}
```

Then call it like :

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitMap(imageUri);
```

Then to save the bitmap into internal storage create a class `ImageStorage`:

```
public class ImageStorage {


public static String saveInternalStorage(Context context,Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

    String stored = null;

    File sdcard = context.getFilesDir();

    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "/directoryName/");
    folder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename + ".jpg") ;

    if (file.exists())
        return stored ;

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        stored = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stored;
}

public static File getImage(Context context,String imagename) {

    File mediaImage = null;
    try {
        String root = context.getFilesDir().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root);
        if (!myDir.exists())
            return null;

        mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/directoryName/"+imagename);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mediaImage;
}
public static boolean checkifImageExists(Context context,String imagename)
{
    Bitmap b = null ;
    File file = ImageStorage.getImage(context,"/"+imagename+".jpg");
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    if (path != null)
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

    if(b == null ||  b.equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true ;
}
}
```

After that call the function with your activity `Context`.

Comment: `File sdcard = context.getFilesDir();`. getFilesDir() is no sd card but internal memory. Please rename your function and variables as now the names are very confusing.

Comment: `and save into local storage.` that should be `and save into internal storage.`.

Comment: `folder.mkdir();` Only call mkdir() if the directory does not exist yet. And check the return value as it might fail.

Comment: `getFilesDir()` is what i'm looking for... With this I don't need to ask storage permission...

Comment: @DouglasFornaro you can upvote the answer if it was helpful enough

Answer (score 1):

If you save profile images to storage than definitely you need read and write permission . 
 
I don't think its a good idea to store image in different folder if you are using it for locally as you mentioned in your question . 
**But,**
If you want to do this without asking for storage permission you can store current image URI (*which you are getting*) into **SharedPreferences** and display profile images using saved URI . 
 **Example  :**

Declare SharedPrefrence in your class :

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static String MYPREFERENCES="MyPrefs";
```

Initialize SharedPrefrence inside onCreate() :

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, 0);
```

Use this sharedprefrence where you are geting you Image URI and save uri in this.
Example :

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("content://x.y.z/"); // Use your URI 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("ProfileImageUri",imgUri);
            editor.apply();
```

Now retrieve this URI from sharedprefrence where you want to set or display user there profile pic .
Example:

```
Uri defaultImageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.profileimage); // use this default image uri if user didn't saved any image to sharedprefrence .

     sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFERENCES, 0);
     ImageURI= sharedpreferences.getString("ProfileImageUri", defaultImageUri.toString);
```

**Now,**

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(ImageURI); 
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```